# Get RSA keys in a "simple" form

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl, rsa

How can I get keys generated by OpenSSL in RAW form? I mean I can't decode my encoded messages in any of online tools. What actions should I do to distribute my keys to other clients (in other apps and web-apps) in proper forms?
My generation code is:

```
void VS_CarrierNet::generateKeys()
{
    m_rsa = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, PUB_EXP, nullptr, nullptr);

    // To get the C-string PEM form:
    BIO *pri = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri, m_rsa, nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub, m_rsa);

    int pri_len = BIO_pending(pri);
    int pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);

    m_privateKey = new char[pri_len + 1];
    m_publicKey = new char[pub_len + 1];

    BIO_read(pri, m_privateKey, pri_len);
    BIO_read(pub, m_publicKey, pub_len);

    m_privateKey[pri_len] = '\0';
    m_publicKey[pub_len] = '\0';

    BIO_free_all(pub);
    BIO_free_all(pri);

    std::cout << "\n\n\n" << m_privateKey << "\n\n\n";
}
```

The example output is:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA1ZI9ucjBwMH2uePmln/xF3mjEIz0WcDQWeI9qZVDXckaFQhr
>   vxDy7GKIuxqEOgcd4zWAGPsyn72i7v2bGxPHXcDdtSqImYk3p2oljBuuQCsbxAxR
>   JXH54D6qUWBMsA5+4K9JVxd//RAhpE/pnXADP6z0O4IP+84m3PtBJjnmaIAOdnx0
>   iM61E1f7QnuaFWhG/K1lljlXCP30yIanKdr4c2iyF+XSF6SqE7ZcLTmFZAR9v+Gh
>   13vpMTwEWGJCUhJJN3Y/83VABWS+HGx7R7nI6IzWwxCcpoLxA67x+m/0WwMuiqDe
>   MXIEDL6HMR7L2eEG80ef8+uSyYVFiGGyH+3AUQIBAwKCAQEAjmF+e9sr1dake+1E
>   ZFVLZPvCCwii5oCK5pbTxmOCPoYRY1ryf2Ch8uxbJ2cC0VoT7M5VZfzMan5sn1O8
>   vLfaPoCTzhxbEQYlGkbDsr0e1XISgrLgw6FRQCnG4OrdyrRUlcow5LpVU2AWbYqb
>   vkqs1R34J6wKp97Ek1IrbtFERal77/J115mYiW/cPlZ4YfOCte2FmxVcvCcT2ZwH
>   4xQCTs9jPzzeMiN5XGIRusKgbK6+5KhyOa3evAT66oXZR96YtBnHZyRR3IElO3nZ
>   Uln2JL5ta0g1FqFWwV8cJed5fAM27JtkyqlVR07j4Dp1/4PlargVIAtGcAnlVoh6
>   pMKuSwKBgQD42ATgBRMWdXzUv/TJ+o8lI5CPK0j2S2zk+jHUn5RD2+obJwPh6a0n
>   sVT6YotYbAe+cQw93g98r5mGFg2OlFnkvS/Iho8Nh24tDCxu1qlaVrpNvja2vi3c
>   afSmNfM0t+KlUkeh88eZYFD9YSE4V4Kz5FZkC4oGcrEh/hK2E0BHHQKBgQDbtovj
>   wFU5z7NcJQUbh+vdyDiOAlBVo1ZyB+rGtaixIUeCEgai4sJMV85HMoo8VPag99i4
>   oueeZ5sF4ovt0ep/bB/MUi+3szTZNwlGdYl9WrTk4+2WRmMSd6uhi6GJaRu21XAl
>   DaxqwXcz/6Xigxh67t0cOFCirsVLiIJEFYlzxQKBgQCl5ViVWLdkTlM4f/iGpwoY
>   wmBfcjCkMkiYpsvjFQ2CkpwSGgKWm8jFIONRlweQSAUpoLLT6V+odREEDrO0YuaY
>   fh/bBF9eWklzXXL0jxuRjybefs8kfsk9m/huzqIjJUHDjC/BTS+7lYtTlhYlj6x3
>   7Y7tXQau9yDBVAx5YiraEwKBgQCSebKX1Y4mineSw1i9BUfpMCW0AYrjwjmhWpyE
>   eRsgwNpWtq8XQdbdj97aIbF9jfnApTslwe++77yulwfz4Ub/nWqINsp6d3iQz1uE
>   Tluo5yNDQp5kLuy2+nJrsmuw8L0kjkrDXnLx1k93/8PsV2WnSei9euBsdIOHsFbY
>   DluigwKBgHHjjR2zHw9wdCB1l66WlIAkT4g2QlX5SM1dbFtSwjIin01NpYrWOhsx
>   TSSjVAGNFXYO1ghl9Eu1rsQEAhQlZ0aCs7l9/v2+xIBmubzFqldjpODR1UPrj9O8
>   Kg3mJD7kG/2ql4dioxy3eTHGkzJBvTwfM/rBhY7rQ4X8ly8c/DvQ
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Should I distribute this key in such form or I need it without additional text and '\n'? I tried remove header, footer, '\n' characters and base64 decode. But this didn't help.

Comment: That's a pretty standard format for SSL keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* the simple form - *including* the header and footer and extra newlines. Most certificate programs can handle this form just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your private key is in PKCS#8 standard form, which is widely used.

You can decrypt RSA messages, for instance, with openssl

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey privkey.pem < ciphertex.bin > plaintext.bin
```

Here `privkey.pem` is a file containing your private key. `ciphertex.bin` is a file containing ecnrypted message and `plaintext.bin` will contain decrypted message.

Comment: Isn't it PKCS#1 form?